# Is static array property not possible in php?

Tags: php, class, static

Below is my code in php,and I am getting error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /LR_StaticSettings.php on line 4

```
<?php
class StaticSettings{
    function setkey ($key, $value) {
        self::arrErr[$key] = $value; // error in this line
    }
}
?>
```

I want to use statically not `$this->arrErr[$key]` so that I can get and set static properties without creating instance/object.

Why is this error? Can't we create static array?

If there is another way, please tell me. Thanks

Comment: Your code doesn't define `$arrErr` as a static member variable. You should declare it as `public static $arrErr = array();`

Comment: No reason for vote down? I find this question help me. So, vote up.
BTW, OP should consider to accept the answer

Answer (score 23):

You'd need to declare the variable as a static member variable, and prefix its name with a dollar sign when you reference it:

```
class StaticSettings{
    private static $arrErr = array();
    function setkey($key,$value){
        self::$arrErr[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

You'd instantiate it like this:

```
$o = new StaticSettings;
$o->setKey( "foo", "bar");
print_r( StaticSettings::$arrErr); // Changed private to public to get this to work
```

You can see it working in [this demo](http://viper-7.com/0q9hBA).

Comment: Hey thanks. I missed $ sign. now it's working.           `class StaticSettings{
    private static $arrErr = array();
    function setkey($key,$value){
        self::$arrErr[$key] = $value;
    }
}` . it was my silly mistake.

Comment: In php there is no need to define variable. we simple use it.  No need to write, `private static $arrErr = array();`

Comment: @user1463076 - That is not true. When you omit it, [a fatal error is produced](http://viper-7.com/JDhBCZ).

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't define `$arrErr` as a static member variable. You should declare it as

```
<?php
class StaticSettings{
    public static $arrErr = array();

    function setkey($key,$value){
        self::arrErr[$key] = $value;
    }
}
?>
```